# Why is my NextJS 14 app not responding when ran in docker container?

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js, dockerfile

I have a Next 14 app running in Docker. The build completes and the console spits out the local and network URLs to access it but when I hit them, they hang or give a message like the host "didn't send any data".

Seems like the next app is starting up fine inside of the Docker container but accessing it is just not working for some reason.

If anyone can provide help or examples of how to get a working docker image for Next 14 that would be great. Below is my docker file for reference:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# 1. Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./
COPY .npmrc ./
COPY ./src/constants/json/account.json ./account.json

ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./account.json

RUN  yarn global add pnpm && pnpm artifact-login && pnpm i; 

# 2. Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
# This will do the trick, use the corresponding env file for each environment.
COPY .env.development .env.production
RUN yarn global add pnpm && pnpm build

# 3. Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./standalone
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static


USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME localhost

CMD ["node", "standalone/server.js"]
```

I've tried running simpler docker versions on freshly created next 14 apps but have had no luck.
Also made sure that the ports were correct using docker ps. they were as expected: `0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem relates to setting `HOSTNAME` at the end of your `Dockerfile`.

Here's a slightly stripped down version that will work. I'd suggest starting with this and then layering on things like `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` until you have what you need.

```
├── Dockerfile
├── next.config.js
├── package.json
└── pages
    ├── _document.js
    └── index.js
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /app

FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

COPY package.json .
COPY .npmrc .

RUN  yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i

FROM base AS builder

COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN yarn global add pnpm && pnpm build

FROM base AS runner

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./standalone
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

CMD ["node", "standalone/server.js"]
```

`next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "standalone",
  productionBrowserSourceMaps: false,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I don't know what your app looks like, but for the purpose of illustration just used a single page that shows that this works.

1. Build image.
2. Run container specifying `-p 3000:3000` to expose port.

[image]